# Google assistant SDK on RaspberryPi 3 - sounddevice.PortAudioError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I get following error when I try to run Sample Google AI as in [Configure and Run the sample](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample)-

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python -m googlesamples.assistant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from googlesamples.assistant import (
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/audio_helpers/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import sounddevice as sd
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2787, in <module>
    _initialize()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2744, in _initialize
    _check(_lib.Pa_Initialize(), 'Error initializing PortAudio')
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2671, in _check
    raise PortAudioError(msg)
sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error initializing PortAudio: Unanticipated host API -10000 error 0: ''
```

Not sure if this is related. But, I also have a *arecord* issue-

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16k --file-type=raw out.raw
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Audio **output** testing as described in [Google AI setup guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/configure-audio) works. Also, I have completed steps 2 to 4 described in link. It does not fix the error though.

This command works -

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16k -D hw:1,0 --file-type=raw out.raw
Recording raw data 'out.raw' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
Warning: rate is not accurate (requested = 16000Hz, got = 44100Hz)
     please, try the plug plugin
```

Is there a solution to get this going?

Thanks.

Comment: I have answered this with a few tips here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374669/google-assistant-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-3-audio-setup-does-not-work/45894404#45894404 x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change ~/.asoundrc to below

```
pcm.!default {
     type asym
     playback.pcm {
             type plug
             slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
     }
     capture.pcm {
             type plug
             slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
     } 
}
```