# Trouble google assistant demo on a raspberry pi 3 and MATRIX Creator mic array

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am getting the following error when I run google-assistant-demo, but `arecord` works fine with `ALSA` capture `file` type:

error:

```
(env)pi:~$ google-assistant-demo 
ALSA lib pcm.c:7918:(snd_pcm_set_params) Sample format not available for CAPTURE: Invalid argument
[3329:3347:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(755)] Input error
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {u'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {u'is_fatal': True}
[3329:3348:ERROR:audio_input_processor.cc(755)] Input error
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {u'is_fatal': True}
```

asoundrc config:

```
pcm.!default
{
  type asym
  playback.pcm {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
  }
  capture.pcm {
    type file
    file "/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8"
    infile "/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8"
    format "raw"
    slave {
        pcm dummy
    }
  }
}
```

The next lines works fine:

```
arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16k --file-type=raw out.raw
aplay --format=S16_LE --rate=16k out.raw
```

Comment: I had same error. Tips are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374669/google-assistant-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-3-audio-setup-does-not-work/45894404#45894404

Answer (score 0):

Copy asoundrc to root as well. Worked in my case. Good luck.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Copy to the root is not working. Do you have any fix for this?